# Which is better: "bidirectionally-anonymous channel" or "bidirectional-anonymous channel"

Tags: technical

I am writing my thesis (in computer science) and me and my supervisor disagree about the correct way of describing a communication channel which is anonymous in both directions. Without delving in too much technicalities, think of this channel as if there is a special button on your mobile phone that, when you click on it, will call someone else in the country, such that you do not get to know his phone number (or any other information about him) nor does he get to know your phone number or any other information about you. You both are anonymous with respect to each others. This is a property of the channel: it provides anonymity to both its ends. So it is bidirectional[ly]-anonymous channel.

Which is the right way in English to describe it:

- Bidirectionally-anonymous channel, or
- Bidirectional anonymous channel?

Thank you.

Comment: ***incognito duplex channel*** :) ! if the channel also can be unidirectional and not anonymous (Although I believe it is not) in unidirectional communication then _Bidirectionally-anonymous channel_ sounds good (since it seems to emphasize on it being birectionally anonymous, i.e. it is anonymous when the communication is bidirectional) else ***Bidirectional anonymous channel*** it is!

Answer (score 1):

"Bidirectionally anonymous" works, because if the channel is not bidirectional in the first place it cannot be bidirectionally anonymous.

Answer (score -1):

The ambiguity might arise because of the understanding of whether or not a channel is inherently bi-directional or not.  To be fully precise you might say "bi-directionally anonymous bi-directional channel" that would clarify the simplex/duplex confusion.

"Bidirectionally anonymous channel" means that that each channel is anonymous and a channel is bi-directional. Otherwise you don't have a need for bi-directionality of anonymity.

"Bidirectional anonymous channel" means that a channel is inherently one directional, but in this case it is bi-directional and at least one of the channels is anonymous.

Bidirectionally anonymous is more concise as the bi-directionality applies to the anonymity as opposed to applying to the channel.